# How to return a plotly figure from a function?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Beginner here so please be gentle! ;)

I am using `plotly` in R to generate some figures.

The code works fine when it is run directly in a script, but fails when I try to output a `plotly` figure from a function.

For example, typing the following in and running directly displays the figure and works fine (`data` is a list containing lots of different parameters):

```
fig1 <- plot_ly(x = 0:100, y = data[[parameter]], type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgba(191,191,191,0.2)'))
fig1
```

I have a lot of plots to do, so have made the following function:

```
Special_plot <- function(data, parameter){fig1 <- plot_ly(x = 0:100, y = data[[parameter]], type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgba(191,191,191,0.2)'))
    return(fig1)
}
```

The function runs, but when it comes to displaying the figure I get an error message:

```
fig1 <- Special_plot(data, parameter) 
fig1
```

This is the error message:

```
Error: Tibble columns must have consistent lengths, only values of length one are recycled:
* Length 0: Column `y`
* Length 101: Column `x`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I have a lot of figures to process and would like to avoid typing each one individually. Any help massively appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide example data with `dput` so we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `x` is going off limits. Maybe try and change the `x` variable like below. Also the `0` index is not present in R. So you have to start with `1`.

```
 Special_plot <- function(data, parameter){ fig1 <- plot_ly(x = 1:length(data[[parameter]]), y = data[[parameter]], type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = 'rgba(191,191,191,0.2)'))
        return(fig1)
    }

fig1 <- Special_plot(data, parameter) 
fig1
```